# Excel row coloring goes beyond the used range

Tags: excel, vba

lemme start by showing a snippet of code

```
For Each cell In selRng.Cells
    If InStr(cell.value, "_cb") Then
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    End If
    If InStr(cell.value, "_mou") Then
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    End If
    If InStr(cell.value, "_ebp") Then
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    End If
Next cell
```

All this code does is that it checks if the end of the string in a cell contains any of those three substrings, after that it will color the while row green.

The issue comes from the fact that the line is gonna be colored way beyond the used range, I tried deleting the extra lines being used in the end but to no avail, there is always one line that remains at the very end of the worksheet where the green lines spill out from.

It looks like this:

[image: Green Lines Spilling]

I know there has to be a way to fix this but I cannot seem to be able to find what exactly is wrong with the code.

Comment: You are not showing all of the relevant part of the code. We need to see where you set `selRng`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict it to the usedrange (which is not always accurate), you could use:

```
Intersect(cell.EntireRow, cell.worksheet.usedrange).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
```

Also, you don't really need three If statements, just one, since it's the same colour each time:

```
If InStr(cell.value, "_cb") Or InStr(cell.value, "_mou") or InStr(cell.value, "_ebp") Then
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! Modified my code as well to have everything in one If condition.

Answer (score 0):

If the last column is always "CB" in all the occasions you can use:

```
Range("A" & cell.Row & ":CB" & cell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
```

However, if last column is not fix you can use:

```
If InStr(cell.Value, "_cb") Or InStr(cell.Value, "_mou") Or InStr(cell.Value, "_ebp") Then
    LastColumn = Worksheets("Data").Cells(cell.Row, Worksheets("Data").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, LastColumn)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
End If
```